# what is the internal working of System.idendityHashCode() and hashCode() method?

Tags: java, hashcode

I read About **System.identityHashCode(Object x)**. You can not override it because its static method but i can override **Object's hashCode** method. and also this is mentioned for **System.identityHashCode(Object x)** in javadoc as :

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides
>        hashCode().The hash code for the null reference is zero.

but when i am running below code by swapping the object in println method i am getting same result.

```
public class SherlockGCD {
    public int hashCode()
      {
       return super.hashCode();
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SherlockGCD sher= new SherlockGCD();
      SherlockGCD sher1= new SherlockGCD();
      System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sher));
      System.out.println(sher1.hashCode());
     }
    }
```

Output is :

31866429

16795905

but if you swap the object as below then also same output

```
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sher1));
    System.out.println(sher.hashCode());
```

Output is :

31866429

16795905

so why output is not **reversing** as i am changing the object in println method??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but when i am running below code by swapping the object in println method i am getting same result.

You shouldn't compare the results of a `hashCode` in one run with the results in a different run. For example, what you *may* have observed is that identity hash codes are allocated lazily - so whichever object you request the hash code for first gets 31866429 and the next gets 16795905 - on your particular system.

If you reverse the order *within a single run* you should see consistent results:

```
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sher));
System.out.println(sher1.hashCode());
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sher1));
System.out.println(sher.hashCode());
```

Here lines 1 and 4 of the output should have the same value, and lines 2 and 3 should have the same value.

Comment: I was surprised about the result for different execution of same program!! Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are trying to do. A given object reference has a given hashCode. This will be returned for both `identityHashCode` and a non-overridden `hashCode`. You however have two different object references. Therefore these will have different hashCodes if `Object.hashCode` is not overriden.

That you are seeing the same hashCodes between runs is chance. If you do this for long enough, and across enough JVM reboots that won't be the case.

The fact that you do see the same hashCodes in the same order is because the hashCodes are being allocated to the object reference only when you first call hashCode, not when the object is created. Therefore the first call to hashCode gets the first code in both runs, regardless of which object it is.

Try

```
  // both lines output the same hashCode for sher
  System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sher));
  System.out.println(sher.hashCode());
```

and

```
  // both lines output the same hashCode for sher1
  System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(sher1));
  System.out.println(sher1.hashCode());
```

If you put all 4 lines next to each other you will see two identical lines, and then two more identical lines different to the first pair.

If you now want to return a different hashCode for `hashCode()` and `identityHashCode` then add a field and return a hashCode inside your override:

```
public class SherlockGCD {
  private int id;
  public SherlockGD(int id) { this.id = id; }
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return id;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: i said output should be reverse as both object are different!!

Comment: You mean between different runs of the same program? That's unlikely. You're seeing an artefact of how hashCodes are generated. For some JVMs they are based on memory address. So your first object and second object just happen to take the same memory (actually internal, not memory) address between the runs you looked at. Wait a little longer and they will probably change completely.

Comment: That's where I got confused. Then I thought jvm will start from some specific address and it will store first object at that address so the different execution are giving same result.